# How to convert an ordinary folder to an reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a react js app, for this reason I have installed node js on my windows machine and executed the command: `npm install -g create-react-app`
inside a directory 'C:\Users\Desktop\ReactDemo'  but the result of command created a directory at AppData\Romaing\npm\create-react-app.

I am surprise why app created in some other directory. My assumption was like if I create an empty directory and from that location in the command line, we init git then that directory becomes git flavored, isn't it.?

Similarly, I am expecting, if I create an empty directory and init react-js flavor that folder should working react-js app, but it isn't instead created a new directory. Can someone please help me understanding how to turn normal directory to working react-js directory.?

Comment: Git init does indeed turn the current directory into a repository, but *installing git doesn't*.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -g create-react-app` install globally create-react-app and it's not the command to create react app.

If you just want to create some app you could use: `npx create-react-app my-app` see: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Additionally please keep in mind that react app created by create-react-app needs to have specific naming convention

Comment: If you want to have reactjs app in folder named ReactDemo then you can use create-react-app to bootstrap project and then move the whole content of the folder to your desired destination.

Comment: @FayazMd Have I addressed your issue? If it solves your issue please mark it as resolved